# Why "Longest Common Subsequence" prohibits "substitution" using edit distance methodology

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

[Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) is a famous class of problems including:

> Different types of edit distance allow different sets of string
> operations. For instance:
>
> 1. The Levenshtein distance allows deletion, insertion and substitution.
> 2. The longest common subsequence (LCS) distance allows only insertion and deletion, not substitution.
> 3. The Hamming distance allows only substitution. Hence, it only applies to strings of the same length.
> 4. The Damerau–Levenshtein distance allows insertion, deletion, substitution, and the transposition (swapping) of two adjacent
>    characters.
> 5. The Jaro distance allows only transposition.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

It mentions:

> The longest common subsequence (LCS) distance allows only insertion and deletion, not substitution.

My doubts:

1. I am confused as to why it does not allow substitution. As far as I understand the algorithm, if there is a character that can be **potentially** matched to a character in the target string, it won't be substituted or deleted.
2. Why does it allow deletion and insertion? Can't it happen that a matching character is deleted because it occurs later in the target string?

I am having a hard time understanding this. For analysis purposes, I have written an [algorithm](https://gist.github.com/Vyom-Yadav/5601cdde60e49090cbc3344d85e1161a) which displays the solution in a grid, like so (It displays trail in color but can't show on SO):

```
$ java dynamic_programming.EditDistance republicans democrats true
|  |  |d |e |m |o |c |r |a |t |s |
|  |0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |
|r |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |5 |6 |7 |8 |
|e |2 |3 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |
|p |3 |4 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|
|u |4 |5 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|
|b |5 |6 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|
|l |6 |7 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|13|
|i |7 |8 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|13|14|
|c |8 |9 |8 |9 |10|9 |10|11|12|13|
|a |9 |10|9 |10|11|10|11|10|11|12|
|n |10|11|10|11|12|11|12|11|12|13|
|s |11|12|11|12|13|12|13|12|13|12|
=========================
12 // (New Edit Distance, Without Substitution)
```

Comment: I found an example. If someone could explain, its still unclear `psnw` `vozsh`, it would give a wrong answer if we allow substitution.

Comment: There is not really a why. Think of it more like "ok, if only insertions and deletions are possible, it makes this edit distance, let's call it LCS". It's a definition, it may be usefull for some problem, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question. Let me try to clarify what do you mean by insertion, deletion and substitution. Consider this code for Levenshtein distance that considers the whole set of operations

```
  for j from 1 to n:
    for i from 1 to m:
      if s[i] = t[j]:
        substitutionCost := 0
      else:
        substitutionCost := 1

      d[i, j] := minimum(d[i-1, j] + 1,                   // deletion
                         d[i, j-1] + 1,                   // insertion
                         d[i-1, j-1] + substitutionCost)  // substitution
```

For the Levenshtein distance, substitution is allowed, therefore if `s[i] != t[j]` then we should, in fact, use the substitution here since it incurs the cost of 1 unit (in other words, `d[i][j] - d[i-1][j-1] <= 1`). However, in the LCS distance, you may observe that substitution is not allowed, and `d[i][j] - d[i-1][j-1] <= 2`, or to say that the cost of up to 2 can be incurred going from d[i-1][j-1] to d[i][j]. This is intuitively true for LCS if you imagine a tracable version of LCS.

Let `s = "abcd", t = "abce"`, consider `d[4][4]`.

- If substitution is disallowed, you can't magically go abcd -> abce, but you have to take two operations abcd -> abc -> abce, the cost is 2.
- If substitution is allowed, however, the cost is 1.

It can be noted that the true LCS distance = |s| + |t| - 2LCS(s, t) = 4 + 4 - 2*3 = 2, which shows that the result is consistent if and only if substitution is not allowed.

Comment: I agree with what you have written, but I don't intuitively understand why we don't allow substitution. Your argument is based on the fact that we don't allow substitution, but my question is *why* we don't allow it.

Comment: Your last statement says the formula won't work correctly if we allow substitution, but that still doesn't answer the question. The formula was created by considering no substitution, so it will of course work for that.

Comment: You can try to implement the traceback to have a better intuition of the cost function.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Traceback_approach

Comment: I already have implemented it, I needed prove instead of checking by testcases.

Comment: Here is the implementation, https://gist.github.com/Vyom-Yadav/5601cdde60e49090cbc3344d85e1161a

Comment: @VIAGC "The formula was created by considering no substitution..." answers your own question. We already know the reasoning of the recurrence for LCS and it does not include substitution.

Comment: @גלעדברקן My question is, "why" not? Can you explain the reasoning?

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood that when using LCS there's three different ways to get from point for example `(0,0)` to point `(1,1)` which are

1. **Path One**: `0,0` -> `0,1` -> `1,1`
2. **Path Two**: `0,0` -> `1,0` -> `1,1`
3. **Path Three**: `0,0` -> `1,1` (diagonal one)

[Small graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTa71.png)

All these paths have same length and are considered to be the same in LCS algorithm, all have same score of 0 (**if there is no match**) even though diagonal path is better and have less editing distance (**one substition** < **one deletion + one insertion**).

Given that, while doing Backtracing it can pick any of these paths resulting in sometimes picking insert+delete path over diagonal one. Resulting longer editing distance (I tried it multiple times on two DNA sequences there's always overestimation).

### Solution

Now, we can solve this problem easily and still use LCS by using **rewards**,

1. Indel paths ---> 0    `sometimes we will be forced to use them if the two strings don't have same length`
2. Diagonal Mismatch --> 1     `more preferable than than indel paths`
3. Diagonal Match --> 2        `best path`

Now, after creating the 2D DP array we can run backtracing code and count Indels and Substitions.

### Python Code

```py
    def DP(seqA: str, seqB: str) -> list:
        r, c = len(seqA), len(seqB)
        nodes =  [ [0]*(c+1) for i in range(r+1) ]
        for i in range(1, r+1):
            for j in range(1, c+1):
                nodes[i][j] = max(
                        nodes[i - 1][j],
                        nodes[i][j - 1],
                        nodes[i-1][j-1] + (seqA[i-1] == seqB[j-1]) + 1
                    )     
        return nodes
    
    def BacktrackAndResult(DP: list[list], seqA, seqB):
        i, j = len(DP)-1, len(DP[0])-1
        mismatches, indel  = 0, 0
        while True:
            if (i == 0 and j == 0):
                break
            else:
                
                if ( j > 0 and i > 0 ):
                    m = (seqA[i-1] == seqB[j-1]) 
                    if (DP[i-1][j-1] + m + 1 == DP[i][j]):
                        if (not m):
                            mismatches+=1
                        else:
                            common+=1
                        i-=1
                        j-=1
                        continue
                if ( i > 0 and DP[i][j] == DP[i-1][j]):
                    indel+=1
                    i-=1
                    continue
                if ( j > 0 and DP[i][j] == DP[i][j-1]):
                    indel+=1
                    j-=1
                    continue
        return (mismatches+indel)
    
    word1, word2 = "ATGT", "AAGT"    
    x = DP(word1, word2)
    print(BacktrackAndResult(x, word1, word2))
```

Comment: you are using substitution but LCS doesn't allows for substitutions.

Comment: @AloisChristen LCS doesn't allow substitution only in case that insertion, deletion and mismatch have same score but this is a modified LCS with different scoring scheme.
By the way, the code attached to the answer have passed Edit Distance Problem on leetcode for all testcases, you can try it